# Laravel create custom method to get form data

Tags: php, laravel-5

How do I make custom method to get form data? I want this method same with Laravel update method with parameters request and id. I try this but get error.

In controller

```
public function updatePassword(Request $request, int $id) {
   dd($request->all());
}
```

In route

```
Route::post('staffs/{id}/upassword', 'Admin\StaffController@updatePassword')->name('admin.staffs.upassword');
```

In blade file

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="{{ action('Admin\StaffController@updatePassword', ['id' => $staff_id]) }}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="password">New Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password">
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
           <div class="form-group">
               <label class="control-label" for="password_confirmation">Confirm New Password</label>
               <input class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" type="password">
           </div>
       </div>
  </div>

  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
</form>
```

I am using Laravel 5.4.

Comment: what is the error u get?

Comment: @NorrisOduro wasn't that my answer already? lol

Comment: @Sletheren lol sorry... i didnt see

Comment: @NorrisOduro lol it's fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are some stuff to fix:

- First in the  tag you can set the action to :
  `action="route('admin.staffs.upassword', $staff_id)"` since it's
  easier to write and since you already gave the route a name, so why
  not using it ;)
- Second add {`{csrf_field() }}` right before your form closing tag
  `</form>`

Comment: I just add `{{ csrf_field() }}` and it works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

what error are you getting? the error is probably because you are not using `{{csrf_field()}}` after the form declaration, it is needed so that laravel can validate the request.  if you want to get the data from the form you can use:

```
$request->get('inputname');
```

Comment: Thank you. It works after I put `{{ csrf_field() }}`.